# Error in syntax of define a trigger in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, triggers

In a table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE "active_mtrs" 
(
     "mtr_ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
     "status" INTEGER, 
     "NIrSTime" DATETIME, 
     "NIrETime" DATETIME
)
```

I defined a trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER "main"."replace1" 
AFTER INSERT ON "active_mtrs" FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @NIrSTime DATETIME;
    DECLARE @NIrETime DATETIME;
    DECLARE @mtr_ID INTEGER DEFAULT 0;

    SELECT @mtr_ID = mtr_ID FROM INSERTED;

    SELECT @NIrSTime = NIrSTime,@NIrETime = NIrETime 
    FROM subscriber 
    WHERE mtr_ID = @mtr_ID;

    UPDATE active_mtrs 
    SET NIrSTime = @NIrSTime,
        NIrETime = @NIrETime 
    WHERE mtr_ID = @mtr_ID; 
END
```

where `subscriber` is another table in this database.

But I get an error:

> [ near "DECLARE": syntax error ]
>   Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
>   Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)

What is my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to use a different SQL dialect in SQLite.

You cannot use DECLARE; you have to look up the values directly:

```
CREATE TRIGGER main.replace1
AFTER INSERT ON active_mtrs
FOR EACH ROW  
BEGIN 
    UPDATE active_mtrs
    SET (NIrSTime, NIrETime) =
            (SELECT NIrSTime, NIrETime
             FROM subscriber
             WHERE mtr_ID = NEW.mtr_ID)
    WHERE mtr_ID = NEW.mtr_ID;
END;
```